# Gradle annotationProcessor for JOOQ checker

Tags: java, sql, gradle, jooq, java-annotations

Does Gradle have an equivalent to the Maven configuration described for the JOOQ type checker annotation processors (https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/tools/checker-framework/)? The Maven version is:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jooq</groupId>
  <artifactId>jooq-checker</artifactId>
  <version>3.10.5</version>
</dependency>
```

And

```xml
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.3</version>
  <configuration>
    <source>1.8</source>
    <target>1.8</target>
    <fork>true</fork>
    <annotationProcessors>
      <annotationProcessor>org.jooq.checker.SQLDialectChecker</annotationProcessor>
    </annotationProcessors>
    <compilerArgs>
      <arg>-Xbootclasspath/p:1.8</arg>
    </compilerArgs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

However, while I can get the compile dependency into Gradle I'm unsure where to put the `annotationProcessor` bit. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15584472/521799

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gradle supports annotation processors since Gradle 3.4 by adding a configuration (e. g. named "apt") for the processors and setting the `annotationProcessorPath`. See [`CompileOptions#setAnnotationProcessorPath()`](https://docs.gradle.org/4.5/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/compile/CompileOptions.html#setAnnotationProcessorPath-org.gradle.api.file.FileCollection-) for details.

Example:

```
configurations {
    apt
}

dependencies {
    apt 'org.jooq: jooq-checker:3.10.5'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.apt
    options.compilerArgs << "-processor" << "org.jooq.checker.SQLDialectChecker"
}
```

Starting with Gradle 4.6 it should even be simpler using the predefined `annotationProcessor`configuration:

```
dependencies {
    annotationProcessor 'org.jooq: jooq-checker:3.10.5'
}
compileJava.options.compilerArgs << "-processor" << "org.jooq.checker.SQLDialectChecker"
```

Also take a look at the [Gradle 4.6-rc.2 release notes](https://docs.gradle.org/4.6-rc-2/release-notes.html#convenient-declaration-of-annotation-processor-dependencies) for details.
And of course there's always potential for improvement: [Make annotation processors a first-class citizen](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2300).

And of course there are a few jOOQ plugins for Gradle which you might want to check out: https://plugins.gradle.org/search?term=jooq

Comment: The officially recommended Gradle plugin is https://github.com/etiennestuder/gradle-jooq-plugin

Comment: Do I not have to specify `org.jooq.checker.SQLDialectChecker` anywhere? I've got Gradle to run, but it isn't actually running the JOOQ checker

Comment: @GaborAngeli I've edited the answer to include the necessary steps for specifying the annotation processor explicitly.

Comment: @LukasEder JOOQ's Gradel plugin does not include or run the checkers, does it?

Comment: @thee: Mind asking a new question, or directly on the plugin's github issue tracker?

Comment: Thanks @joschi! I wish the jooq guys would stick this in their documentation along side the maven instructions.