# Jooq Checker with Gradle and Java 11

Tags: gradle, jooq

I simply want to activate the SQLDialectChecker mentioned here [SQLDialectChecker](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.17/manual/tools/checker-framework/) in my Java 11 project with Gradle (7.5).

I added

```
dependency {
  ...
  annotationProcessor 'org.jooq.pro-java-11:jooq-checker:3.17.5'
}
```

and

```
compileJava.options.compilerArgs << "-processor" << "org.jooq.checker.SQLDialectChecker"
```

to my build.gradle as described here in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48998648/gradle-annotationprocessor-for-jooq-checker).

Now the compilation fails with

```
org.checkerframework.javacutil.UserError: The Checker Framework must be run under JDK 1.8.  You are using version 11.000000.
```

Is it possible to use the SQLDialectChecker for Java version above 1.8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the Jooq-Checker only runs with Java 8 and possible support of newer JDK's does not seem to be easy and has no high priority, see [Issue-13963](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/13963) and [Issue-8326](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/8326).